# Error(s): *** buffer overflow detected ***: 739027069/a.out terminated Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Tags: c

I have a code which was working fine with window's compiler but when I tried to convert it in linux compiler I got the error
Error(s):
*** buffer overflow detected ***: 739027069/a.out terminated
Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

I'm running the code in an online compiler
https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
static struct termios old, current;

void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  current = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  if (echo) {
      current.c_lflag |= ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  } else {
      current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; /* set no echo mode */
  }
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}
void func(){
    for(;;){
  char val;
  char input[] = " ";
  printf("Type formula:\n");
  do {
    val = ' ';
    val = getche();
    strncat(input, & val, 1);
  } while (val != '=');
  int ilen, tlen = 0;
  ilen = strlen(input);
  char * fop, * sop, op;
  op = '/';
  fop = strtok(input, "/");
  tlen = strlen(fop);
  if (ilen == tlen) {
    op = '*';
    fop = strtok(input, "*");
    tlen = strlen(fop);
    if (ilen == tlen) {
      op = '+';
      fop = strtok(input, "+");
      tlen = strlen(fop);
      if (ilen == tlen) {
        op = '-';
        fop = strtok(input, "-");
        tlen = strlen(fop);
        if (ilen == tlen) {
          printf("\nInvalid input.\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sop = strtok(NULL, "=");  
double fd,sd;
fd = strtod(fop, NULL);
sd = strtod(sop, NULL);
if(fd==0||sd==0)
{
printf("\nInvalid input.\n" );
return 0;   
}
int res = 0;
   switch(op) {
      case '+' :
        res = fd + sd;
         printf("\n%d\n",res);
         break;
      case '-' :
        res = fd - sd;
         printf("\n%d\n",res);
         break;
      case '*' :
        res = fd * sd;
         printf("\n%d\n",res);
         break;
      case '/' :
        res = fd / sd;
         printf("\n%d\n",res);
         break;
      default :
         printf("\nInvalid input.\n" );
   }
  return 0;   
}
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 func();
}
```

Comment: `char input[] = " ";` There's no space allocated to allow you to concatenate to this string. Consider something like `char input[128] = {0};` to allocate enough space for 128 characters. Adjust the number to suit your needs.

Comment: Kinda speaks volumes about the window's compiler you were using....